# nalgebra: Implementing a function for a generic MatrixMN

Tags: rust, nalgebra

I'm trying to implement the exp function for a generic square MatrixMN

```rust
pub fn exp<N, R>(m: &MatrixMN<N, R, R>, k: usize) -> MatrixMN<N, R, R>
where
    N: Scalar + One + Zero,
    R: DimName + DimNameAdd<R>,
    <R as DimName>::Value: Mul<<R as DimName>::Value>,
    <<R as DimName>::Value as Mul<<R as DimName>::Value>>::Output: generic_array::ArrayLength<N>,
{
    let mut i = MatrixMN::<N, R, R>::identity();
    i.add(&m)
}
```

But I keep getting this errors like this.

```
error[E0599]: no method named `add` found for struct `nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<N, R, R, nalgebra::base::array_storage::ArrayStorage<N, R, R>>` in the current scope
  --> src/state_extrapolation.rs:24:7
   |
24 |     i.add(&m)
   |       ^^^ method not found in `nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<N, R, R, nalgebra::base::array_storage::ArrayStorage<N, R, R>>`
   |
   = note: the method `add` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&mut nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<N, R, R, nalgebra::base::array_storage::ArrayStorage<N, R, R>> : nalgebra::base::dimension::DimNameAdd<_>`
           `&nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<N, R, R, nalgebra::base::array_storage::ArrayStorage<N, R, R>> : nalgebra::base::dimension::DimNameAdd<_>`
           `nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<N, R, R, nalgebra::base::array_storage::ArrayStorage<N, R, R>> : nalgebra::base::dimension::DimNameAdd<_>`
```

Is there a better way to pass generic matrices to functions?

I've also tried with something like this

```rust
pub fn exp2<M>(m: &M, k: usize) -> M
where
    M: nalgebra::base::Matrix<_, _, _, _>,
{
    let mut i = M::identity();

    i.add(&m)
}
```

But cannot come up with good traits for M.

Comment: By the way, there's the `MatrixN` type for square matrices.

Comment: Do you want your function to work with fixed-size matrices only or also dynamically sized ones?

Comment: Fixed size is good enough, thanks for MatrixN, I'll update my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to get lost in the traits when making things fully generic. My tips are:

- Copy the signature of the impl block that implements similar functions to yours, e.g. the line `DefaultAllocator: Allocator<N, R, R>` from [here](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.20.0/nalgebra/base/type.MatrixN.html) allows getting rid of many constraints
- Instead of `Scalar`, if it's going to be floats you will calculate with, it's easier to use `RealField` which gives you `Scalar` plus many other useful properties (like `One` and `Zero` required for the `identity()` function)
- Follow the compiler errors – it suggested I add a `use std::ops::Add`, which made it work in the end.

Here is the code, [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=205fed4866948b0a0c417e68630e761f):

```
use nalgebra::{
    base::allocator::Allocator, DefaultAllocator, DimName, DimNameAdd, MatrixN, RealField,
};
use std::ops::Add;

fn exp<N, R>(m: &MatrixN<N, R>, k: usize) -> MatrixN<N, R>
where
    N: RealField,
    R: DimName + DimNameAdd<R>,
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<N, R, R>,
{
    let i = MatrixN::<N, R>::identity();
    m.add(i)
}
```

Comment: Can I just ask, what does DefaultAllocator: Allocator<N, R, R> actually do?

Comment: It seems like nalgebra allows switching out allocators with anything that implements the Allocator trait. I guess the Allocator trait needs to calculate the memory requirement for your matrix (size_of::<N>() * R * C) which is why it needs R and C to be multiply-able.

Comment: Syntactically, it's sort of an inverse trait bound, where you have a concrete type on the left and a generic trait that it satisfies on the right, like `f64: From<N>`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I could help :)